# What is the German word for "you can't change the user experience because your users are used to it"?

Tags: word-choice, technical-terminology

I was working with a website designer in Sydney who had just worked in Germany. We were talking about a website features we wanted to remove and replace with new ones.

We came across a scenario where some website features were stuck in "user muscle memory". We couldn't improve them, despite them being bad because the users were used to it.

The website designer said:

> You know there is a German word for this scenario. It's the same word as divorce restitution in German family law. You want to change, but you have to keep things the same because that is what everyone is used to.

My question is: What is the German word for "you can't change the user experience because your users are used to it"?

Comment: Could it be "Gewohnheitsrecht"? (in English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custom_%28law%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say that the users are affected by the "Gewöhnungseffekt".